# Can a 9 volt battery through your bloodstream kill you?

Tags: batteries, electricity

I usually try to do some research before asking questions on this site, but everything I've found has been contradictory.

If I were to direct the positive and negative ends of a 9 volt battery through open wounds on either of my hands, allowing the electricity to travel through my bloodstream and presumably past my heart, would it kill me? What if I were able to let go as soon as I felt the shock?

Comment: OK, having researched this, you've certainly already found estimates for the resistance of the human body; apply these, figure out how much current flows, question answered.

Comment: I've found lots of different data from my research. Also, I don't know if touching it for a fraction of a second would kill.

Comment: Listing a few of your sources would help.

Comment: I've read that the resistance of blood can be anywhere between 200 to 1000 Ohms, I'm assuming depending mainly on distance? At 9 volts couldn't those numbers make the difference between severe burns and death?

Comment: "I've read" <-- where. *Cite your sources*. Learn to work with your sources, contextualize them, assess their quality. The answer to your question is not being the 200th person to ask the question with slightly different parameters (e.g. with 9V instead of 12V. There's a 12V question on this site already), but to *understand* under which circumstances electricity is lethal.

Comment: [link]https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-electrical-resistance-of-human-body
[link]http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1902Natur..66..127T

Comment: please edit your question to include these links and the specific things you'd quote from them.

Comment: neither sources are appropriate – the first *explains* that you'd only need to look at the *internal resistance* of the human body, but doesn't put a number to it, the second looks at blood as material, but the human body is only to a small percentage (6L of much, much more) made out of blood.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll do some more research next time before I ask

Comment: A 9V battery is sufficiently large to block any artery...

Comment: I have read authorative papers (which I may be able to locate but Garglabet is usually faster than me) that state that IF you get currents onto the heart surface then much much  much  much  much  ... lower than usually stated  currents can kill. Say 10's to 100's of uA range. ... Here we go : [Electrical Safety in the Operating Room: Dry Versus Wet](https://journals.lww.com/anesthesia-analgesia/pages/articleviewer.aspx?year=2010&issue=06000&article=00001&type=Fulltext) ...

Comment: ... Microshock refers to very small currents (as little as 10–50 μA) and applies only to the electrically susceptible patient, such as an individual who has an internal conduit that is in direct contact with the heart. This conduit can be a pacing wire or a saline-filled central venous or pulmonary artery catheter. In the electrically susceptible patient, even minute amounts of current (10 μA) may cause ventricular fibrillation.

Comment: Once started ventricular fibrillation may well not stop without external action - electro shock - whose purpose is NOT to supply a heart start signal but to FULLY STOP the fibrillation signals so that the normal heart waveforms can re-establish.

Comment: The resistance between any two points on the body is likely to be different depending on location, the specific person, and any other external factors.  Any typical or average numbers you look up are just that (typical / averages) and are likely to be inaccurate for any specific person.  Have you tried just measuring the resistance between said points with a good multimeter?

Comment: Also, if the current level is the difference between life or death, then clearly add something to limit the current.  Even a $0.10 100K ohm resistor in series with the battery would do it.

Comment: I've reopened this in February 2024. The information given in answers and comments allows a good assessment of what is involved and the likely probability - which informs the level of risk aversion which would be wise. || T L;DR: prudent avoidance. Very unlikely. Possible. You'd have no comeback if it killed you :-( :-)

Answer (score 4):

IF you get cause currents in the 10's of microamps range onto the actual surface of the heart death can occur.

This paper makes that statement [**Electrical Safety in the Operating Room: Dry Versus Wet**](https://journals.lww.com/anesthesia-analgesia/pages/articleviewer.aspx?year=2010&issue=06000&article=00001&type=Fulltext) and my recollection is that the writer has come to specialise in establishing best safety practices in that area.

He says:

> Microshock refers to very small currents (as little as 10–50 μA) and
> applies only to the electrically susceptible patient, such as an
> individual who has an internal conduit that is in direct contact with
> the heart. This conduit can be a pacing wire or a saline-filled
> central venous or pulmonary artery catheter. In the electrically
> susceptible patient, even minute amounts of current (10 μA) may cause
> ventricular fibrillation.

Once started, the chaotic rhythm known as ventricular fibrillation (VF) will often not stop by itself without external intervention - usually a **very** high magnitude electric shock from a defibrillator*- whose purpose is NOT to supply a heart start signal but to FULLY STOP the fibrillation rhythm so that the normal heart waveforms (normal sinus rhythm) can be restored.

*A defibrillator is usually a purpose designed item of medical equipment. In an emergency any source of significant but not too-significant electrical energy can be used and **may* work. Risk of causing death or injury by this means is high and the risks of acting or not acting need to be weighed. (In a long ago movie the 'hero' used a mains cord from a torn apart table lamp as a defibrillator to successfully save a life. You'd need to be brave, desperate and lucky to perform such a feat successfully. In some cases it may be the best choice :-(.)

[image: Normal sinus rhythm (NSR) vs Ventricular fibrillation (VF)]

Answer (score 1):

This question stems from the rumor that some navy tech wanted to test the conductivity of their body so they pushed the meter beneath their skin and got electrocuted. (at least the version I heard, I'm sure there are many variants by now.)

Yes, it can, it only takes 10-20mA to stop a human heart. A 9V battery can provide much more than that. Your [skin has sufficient resistance](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/404346/can-10-100ma-kill-a-person-be-deadly/404356#404356) that it can stop current. If the skin is broken the resistance drops significantly. The current must be across the heart.

> Offhand it would seem that a shock of 10,000 volts would be more
>   deadly than 100 volts. But this is not so! Individuals have been
>   electrocuted by appliances using ordinary house currents of 110 volts
>   and by electrical apparatus in industry using as little as 42 volts
>   direct current. The real measure of shock's intensity lies in the
>   amount of current (amperes) forced though the body, and not the
>   voltage. Any electrical device used on a house wiring circuit can,
>   under certain conditions, transmit a fatal current.
>
> While any amount of current over 10 milliamps (0.01 amp) is capable of
>   producing painful to severe shock, currents between 100 and 200 mA
>   (0.1 to 0.2 amp) are lethal. Currents above 200 milliamps (0.2 amp),
>   while producing severe burns and unconsciousness, do not usually cause
>   death if the victim is given immediate attention. Resuscitation,
>   consisting of artificial respiration, will usually revive the victim.
>
> From a practical viewpoint, after a person is knocked out by an
>   electrical shock it is impossible to tell how much current has passed
>   through the vital organs of his body. Artificial respiration must be
>   applied immediately if breathing has stopped.

Source: https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/physics/p616/safety/fatal_current.html

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a new answer that will be more precise after more resarch.

- The internal resistance of the body from hand to hand will be something like >300ohm
- I = U/R
- I = 9V / 300ohm = 30mA

DC current is about 2-4 times less dangerous than AC current because the AC current will cause faster ventricular fibrillation which is often the cause of death from electric shock.

[image: Human body resistance]

So what rates are dangerous?

[image]

> If I were to direct the positive and negative ends of a 9 volt battery through open wounds on either of my hands, allowing the electricity to travel through my bloodstream and presumably past my heart, would it kill me? What if I were able to let go as soon as I felt the shock?

Applying 9V from your hand to hand directly in your bloodstream would then give 30mA DC which is highly unlikely to kill you.

- What if you applied the battery straight on your heart?
- We know the resistance hand to hand is about 300ohms. The length is about 150cm+- and we use 10cm for the heart, reduce to ~20ohms. I = 9V/20 = 450mA. This number would get close to possible heart fibrillation.

While not pleasant it seems that connecting a 9V battery directly to your heart is in the danger zone but not necessarily going to kill you. Connecting a 9V battery however from hand to hand in the bloodstream is highly unlikely to kill you.

Comment: Yes. It can. See my answer.

Comment: Interesting. It seems that direct contact with the hearth is lethal at 30mA+ then according to your source. However hand to hand shouldn't be

Comment: 10-50 MICRO amp. And, yes, hand to hand at 9V is extremely unlikely. People have died with 12V across the chest with good contact. -> Long ago experiment with consenting convict subjects . Death was not expected :-(.  I do not have refs. Pre-internet memory. Seems liable to be a valid memory. Validity of actual ref unknown.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon yes I said 30mA because that's my calculated approximate value hand to hand. interesting read

Comment: Why are the figures for 10 kHz AC not somewhere _between_ 60 Hz AC and DC (= infinity Hz AC)?

Answer (score 1):

> "It's the volts that jolts, but the mills that kills"

Roughly speaking, humans can feel voltage (via muscular contraction) but death comes from milliamps of current passing through the sinoatrial node near the heart.

If you could construct a scenario where you could present a conductive path that includes the sinoatrial node, of resistance less than about 90Ω, to the terminals of a 9V battery, then you might have an electrocution risk. The human blood vessel system with wounds at either end is probably not sufficient. But since the 1930's, experiments of this nature have fallen out of favour so the state of the art is really just a lot of extrapolation.

The state of the art is that <120Vdc is low risk in normal circumstances, but you could still come up with a scenario with electrocution risk. Thus <60Vdc is often used as a safer limit in various worldwide standards. Finally, in particular hazardous scenarios like swimming pools (think of underwater lighting), <25Vdc is required to be considered safe.

9V is considerably lower than this already very low limit, so would take some very special circumstances to present an electrocution risk. But I reckon if you worked hard enough at it, you could kill some very unlucky, highly susceptible, high sodium content individual.

To answer your second question: yes, it is possible to let go and save yourself - electrocution only occurs if the shock coincides with a vulnerable phase (about 10%) of the sinus cycle. At 9V the muscular convulsion would not be enough to render you paralysed, so if you're lucky, you might be able to sense the shock and disconnect before the vulnerable period arrives.

Comment: I know of a person who was killed by electrocution doing a charging check on a helicopter 28V system in torrential rain. He slipped and grabbed the main busbar.

Comment: I have a friend (still living) who achieved "total muscle lockup" with 12V from a faulty flounder fishing light while standing in salt water.

Comment: @PeterSmith Are you able to provide some sort of reference to the helicopter battery fatality. It would help my discussions elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

> If I were to direct the positive and negative ends of a 9 volt battery through open wounds on either of my hands, allowing the electricity to travel through my bloodstream and presumably past my heart, would it kill me?

Other answers have addressed the electrical interaction with the heart's rhythm center and conduction systems - the aspects typically associated with electric shock.

A 9V battery in the scenario you propose is a bit more insidious since if your heart won't be instantaneously affected, you'll be bound to think "oh, it's not doing anything".

Well, it is actually doing something and that is facilitating galvanic chemical reactions that will be destroying the various components of the blood (a liquid tissue), and the tissues adjacent to the site of the contact with the battery terminals. A 9V battery discharging through the bloodstream will definitely not make you feel any good the longer you keep it going. The charge in a 2032 coin cell is enough to cause pretty bad lesions in the moist environment of esophagus - bad enough to cause life-long complications and death if untreated. And that is a completely intact 2032 cell with nothing leaching out - just the stored charge in it is able to do a lot of localized damage.

A 9V battery's worth of charge going through the bloodstream is not going to be a fun experience in any shape or form. Leave it connected until it fully discharges and the experiment may be interrupted by systemic effects bad enough to warrant an emergency room visit. Do not try this at home, folks.

Answer (score -5):

Electricity shouldn't be much different if it hits you in a wound or not. It's not traveling on the outside of your skin, outside a wound and then going in only at the wound. A 9v battery shouldn't kill a human though.

Comment: *A 9v battery shouldn't kill a human* A 9V battery has plenty enough charge in it to make a hole through the abdominal wall etc. - it's just a matter of connecting it long enough to do the damage. A special 9V battery covered in biocompatible plastic with biocompatible electrode material, just to show that the effect is due to charge only, inserted anywhere in the abdomen, may well work its way out of the body in a couple of days. As in: it'll eat out a hole and fall out. It won't kill a human from short-term contact, but let it be attached long term and it'll be seriously bad.